While Expanding ExpandableTile remove divider between title and childer in flutter
Want to remove divider between title and children when expanding tile.
Tried two ways but not able to make it transparent, Want divider after the children but not between title and children.
The ways, I have tried
    ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.faq?.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final faq = state.faq![index];
                  return Theme(
                    data: Theme.of(context)
                        .copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.red),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ExpansionTile(
                          shape: Border(),
                          title: Text(
                            faq.question!,
                            style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular
                                .copyWith(color: CoreColor.black),
                          ),
                          trailing: state.faq![index].isExpanded
                              ? Assets.coreSvgs.downwardArrow.svg()
                              : Assets.coreSvgs.forwardArrow.svg(),
                          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              state.faq![index].isExpanded = value;
                            });
                          },
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                              child: Text(
                                faq.answer!,
                                style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular
                                    .copyWith(color: CoreColor.neutral600),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        const Divider(
                          color: CoreColor.neutral200,
                          height: 0,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
// 2nd ways
                      return ExpansionTile(
                        tilePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                        shape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            state.faq![index].isExpanded = value;
                          });
                        },
                        trailing: state.faq![index].isExpanded
                            ? Assets.coreSvgs.downwardArrow.svg()
                            : Assets.coreSvgs.forwardArrow.svg(),
                        title: Text(
                          faq.question!,
                          style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular
                              .copyWith(color: CoreColor.black),
                        ),
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              faq.answer!,
                              style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular
                                  .copyWith(color: CoreColor.neutral600),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),



Your both approach works fine from my side.

Try removing the shape parameter in your ExpansionTiles, which according to the docs, controls "The tile's border shape when the sublist is expanded", or specifying transparent horizontal borders, similar to what you did here:
ExpansionTile(
    tilePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
    shape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),


not working, i tried it
